# Qual a melhor forma de fazer a verificação? (Try-catch, multiples if,...?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, try-catch

Estou lendo milhares de arquivos XML com python. O problema é, nem sempre há o campo em todos os arquivos.

```
    resumo_cv = root.find("DADOS-GERAIS").find("RESUMO-CV").get("TEXTO-RESUMO-CV-RH")
    resumo_cv_ingles = root.find("DADOS-GERAIS").find("RESUMO-CV").get("TEXTO-RESUMO-CV-RH-EN")
    palavras_chave_mestrado = root.find("DADOS-GERAIS").find("FORMACAO-ACADEMICA-TITULACAO").find("MESTRADO").find("PALAVRAS-CHAVE")
    list_palavras_chave_mestrado = ""
    if palavras_chave_mestrado is not None:
         for palavra, valor in palavras_chave_mestrado.items():
         if valor is not None and valor != "":
              list_palavras_chave_mestrado =
```

No caso, o codigo acima ficaria assim:

```
dados_gerais = root.find("DADOS-GERAIS")
if dados_gerais is not None:
    resumo_cv = dados_gerais.find("RESUMO-CV")
    if resumo_cv is not None:
        texto_resumo_cv = resumo_cv.get("TEXTO-RESUMO-CV-RH")
        if texto_resumo_cv is None:
            texto_resumo_cv = ''
        texto-resumo_cv_ingles = resumo_cv.get("TEXTO-RESUMO-CV-RH-EN")
        if resumo_cv_ingles is None:
            texto_resumo_cv_ingles = ''
```

Ou seja, uma verificação para cada campo (find) e (get). Sem contar, que alguns campos dos XML tenho que percorrer listas...
Há alguma forma otimizada utilizando try-cacth ou qualquer outra coisa? Hahah obg.

Comment: E esses métodos lançam alguma exceção nos casos citados? Se não lançam, não adianta usar `try/catch`.

Comment: Apenas ambos retornam None caso não encontrados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer validação em arquivos XML é utilizando um esquema de validação.

Geralmente utiliza-se DTDs. Um tutorial básico (em inglês) na utilização de DTDs para validação de arquivos XML pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://lxml.de/validation.html). Mais informações sobre DTDs podem ser encontradas [neste artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition). Mais informações sobre outros métodos de validação XML pode ser encontrados [neste outro artigo, também da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_validation).

No caso acima, você tenta acessar os campos do seu XML. Existem formas mais gerais de realizar parsing em XML como o implementado [neste projeto do GitHub](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict). Talvez esse útlimo link seja suficiente para resolver o seu problema de forma bem mais elegante.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo material Arthur, vou atrás! =)

Comment: Marca como respondido ;)